# Number of all finite sequences of positive integers that add up to 100 (with some constraints)

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, integer-partitions

> Find the number of all finite sequences of integers $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$, such that
> $$
> n_1 + n_2 + ⋯ + n_k = 100
> $$
> and such that for every $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$ we have $n_i \ge i$.

I have been thinking about this for days but I still do not understand how to begin. Please help.

Comment: title and body seem different -- do you want monotone sequences or $n_i \ge i$? E.g. the sequence $40,60$ is both but $60,40$ is ok for (2) but not ok for (1)

Comment: My bad for the title

Comment: Okay, I think it should make sense now. If not, ignore the title; problem is for sure right.

Comment: It's fine if you don't know how a nice and finished solution begins. That's why you're here in the first place. However, that doesn't mean you don't know where _you_ should begin. There are always things you can do. Answer small parts of the problem, for instance. If we, say, fix $k=4$, can you solve the problem? How many solutions are there to $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=100$ if each $n_i\geq i$? What's the largest possible $k$? These kinds of questions are usually easier to answer and has the added bonus of taking you a step closer a finished solution.

Comment: In short, when you say you don't know where to begin, [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: You can *begin* by  trying to list them all, hundred $1$s, then ninety-eight $1$s and a $2$, the ninety-seven $1$ and a $3$, and so on.  Maybe do a simple case of all the sequences that add to a small number like $5$.  ($1,1,1,1,1$:$1,1,1,2$:$1,1,3$:$1,4$.$1,2,2$:$2,3$:$5$ seven of them.Then another number such as $6$.. if we start with $1$ the rest must add to $5$ we already know there are $7$. then if we start with $2$ we have $2,2,2$ or $2,4$ and $3,3$ so there are $10$.  Can we figure a pattern.

Comment: You are right Arthur, I should have given more information; my mistake. I am new to the site btw nice meeting you all!

Comment: When $k = 2$, you have $98$ possible sequences if i) $n_1, n_2$ can be same $(50, 50)$ and ii) $(2, 98)$ is different than $(98, 2)$. Can you tell if i) and ii) are to be counted in?

Comment: Yes, i) and ii) are to be counted in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible approach / might not be the fastest way.

Fix a certain $k$, then the problem becomes finding non-negative integers $a_i = n_i - i$ s.t.

$$\sum a_i = 100 - \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

which can be solved by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Then just loop through all possible values of $k$.  Can you finish from here (if this approach is OK with you)?

Comment: +1 beat me by 30 secs :)

Comment: @gt6989b oh i'm sorry!  :D you deleted answer is a very nice writeup.  feel free to revive it.  i only beat you because i left out all the nice details in your answer!

Comment: Great solution!